# How to call up a particular contact in Android...?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am a newbie.
I was looking for a way to :

use **ACTION_DIAL INTENT** and callup a **particular contact** like say by the name of **"HOME"**. I guess we have to use get_Data() and ContactsContract, but have no clue of how to use it...

I looked for a while but only got (ACTION_DIAL,uri.parse("tel:XXXXXXX"))

Can anyone Please help ?
Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following example helps you.

The example is about postal address but you can get your desired info

[Get Postal address from a contact using ContactsContract api on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609700/get-postal-address-from-a-contact-using-contactscontract-api-on-android)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply anuja :)
Actually what i want to do is NOT TELL THE USER to PICK A Contact, Instead dial a particular contact from the app itself,
like there is a button of the name "HOME", when the user clicks it, android system must call HOME from his contact book directly......